# AndroidX MaterialButton does not show style

Tags: android, android-button, androidx, android-styles, material-components-android

I have a LinearLayout where I put programmatically buttons in it. At the beginning there is one button inside which is there to add new filter buttons. The XML is as follows:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/filterContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/addFilterButton"
                style="@style/iconButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_list_icon_color" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

If the filter button is pressed then new filters can be added. There are added to the ViewGroup which is the LinearLayout like this:

```
private void addButtonForFilter(ResultFilter filter) {
    MaterialButton newFilter = new MaterialButton(mFilterBoxViewGroup.getContext(),
            null, R.attr.materialButtonStyle);
     newFilter.setText(FilterStringProvider.getLabel(mFilterBoxViewGroup.getContext(), filter));
    newFilter.setLayoutParams(mParameters);
    newFilter.setOnClickListener(this);
    newFilter.setTag(filter.getFilterType());
    mFilterBoxViewGroup.addView(newFilter);
}
```

Here the buttons are shown in the standard material design. Now I would like to change it to a specific style.

```
<style name="textButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorActionbarTabs</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/itemColor</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/item_standard_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
</style>
```

If I change the styling in the constructor of the code above then the button is not showing up as expected:

```
    MaterialButton newFilter = new MaterialButton(mFilterBoxViewGroup.getContext(),
            null, R.style.textButton);
```

The button is now showing with no padding even if the new style has the MaterialButton as parent and I was not able to find out what is causing this behavior. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of the `MaterialButton` is:

```
MaterialButton(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
```

The **3rd** parameter is **`defStyleAttr`** and it is an **attribute** defined in your **app theme**, it is **not** a style.

For example `R.attr.materialButtonStyle`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
</style>
```

With the `1.1.0` and `1.2.0-beta01` there are 3 built-in attrs defined:

```
<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
<item name="materialButtonOutlinedStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton</item>
<item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton</item>
```

The `1.3.0-alpha01` introduced a new attr:

```
<item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton</item>
```

**You can use one of these attrs overriding them in your app theme:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/textButton</item>
</style>
```

and then use:

```
MaterialButton newFilter = new MaterialButton(mFilterBoxViewGroup.getContext(),
            null, R.attr.buttonBarButtonStyle);
```